# How To Delete Multiple Rows from Table Using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to delete multiple rows from my `post_tags` table where `post_id` is given .

table structure `post_tags` is : **post_id , tag_id , created_at , updated_at**

I am able to do this operation with `DB query builder` , but i want to

> delete multiple rows with single elequent command without using forloop

I don't know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
$post_id = [1,2,3];

DB::table('post_tags')
->whereIn('id',$post_id)
->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Model::destroy($ids)` an array. Alternatively, loop the records you want to delete and call `delete` on each: `$model->postTags->each->delete()`.